# Discrepancy when using group by clause

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery

I see a discrepancy in the count because of the group by clause, please advise how to go about this.

Total records in the table are 4638 when I do count(you_id), but when I run this script I'm getting only 4544 records.

```
SELECT
    thumbnails,
    CR1,
    monetize,
    c_id,
    you_id,
    vendor,
    ratio * 100 AS percent
FROM
(
    SELECT thumbnails, c_id,you_id, vendor,CR1,monetize,timestamp,
           count(*) AS total, RATIO_TO_REPORT(total) OVER() AS ratio
    FROM testing
    GROUP by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
);
```

Comment: Query:
SELECT thumbnails,CR1, monetize,c_id, you_id,vendor, ratio * 100 AS percent FROM ( SELECT thumbnails, c_id,you_id, vendor,CR1,monetize,timestamp, count(*) AS total, RATIO_TO_REPORT(total) OVER() AS ratio FROM testing GROUP by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 );

Comment: Can you explain what is the discrepancy here?

Comment: Update your question with sample data, current and expected output.  Your question is not answerable in its current form because nobody can read your mind.

Comment: Total records in the table are 4638 when I do count(you_id), but when I run this script I'm getting only 4544 records.

Comment: Can you provide sample data so we can take a look at it?

Comment: ( a job id would help if internal debugging needed too)

Comment: Wouldn't you get this result if there were rows that shared the same values for those 7 columns?

Comment: Tim your answer with a small tweak in the query by moving 'RATIO_TO_REPORT(total) OVER() AS ratio' into the initial Select query worked.